# How to have android-like force dark mode on windows 10

Tags: windows, colors, themes, dark-mode

So on android, a force dark mode turns white background of ALL apps to the black and make text light even for the apps which do not have dark mode settings or the ones which do not follow system settings. It works on that by changing colors when they are rendered on the screen. SO it applies to all apps and settings with a single toggle.

Apparently this is not possible in Windows 10 with my research as of now. But if I have missed, is there a such functionality so that I do not have to go in each specific app and change settings and also use dark theme in windows settings just to change overall theme? It would be much easier if it would be a single switch. Currently closest I can get to is to toggle color filters and invert colors. But this distorts the colors of images as well. Similar is the case with Negative Screen software. It does the job but destroys colors in images, videos as well i.e. inverts all the colors. What I am looking for is a selective inversion mechanism which intelligently inverts only where needed. Is there a good approach to do this? I am also fine with being locked into dark mode but turning all apps settings to dark mode does not guarantee complete dark mode as some apps simply does not have dark mode. How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default behavior of the OS to Dark Mode. If the application has an option to set a theme, choosing "system default settings" will allow the app to honor the Dark Mode settings.

In order to turn it on you'll need at least version 1607 (the Anniversary Update), the latest being version 20H2. You can turn it on by navigating to the Colors settings:

`Start > Settings > Personalization > Colors > Choose your color: Dark`

Comment: Yeah but it does not apply everywhere. Thats the kind of point

Comment: @Hamza If the app doesn't support system default themes, that's an issue with the app. You'll have to take it up with them. Visual Studio's Installer, a Microsoft product, didn't even support Dark Mode until last month.

Comment: It applies to almost all Windows 10 compliant software. There is so much software that some is bound to be a problem.